# In Mysql While using JOIN for 3 tables getting the same output multiple times in the array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables one with single row for an id and the other two with multiple rows for the same id.

I wrote a query to join the 3 tables

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$joinSelect = "
    SELECT form_submitted.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(form_submitted_news.news) as news,
    GROUP_CONCAT(form_submitted_language.language) as LANGUAGE
    FROM form_submitted 
    JOIN form_submitted_news ON form_submitted.id = form_submitted_news.cid
    JOIN form_submitted_language ON form_submitted.id = form_submitted_language.cid
    WHERE form_submitted.id='$id'
        AND form_submitted_language.cid='$id' 
        AND form_submitted_news.cid='$id' 
        GROUP BY form_submitted.id
";  

$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$joinSelect);

$update4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);

print_r($update4);
```

But when i print the array i am getting repeated values in these two tables with has multiple rows ->form_submitted_news and form_submitted_language

Output:

```
Array (
 [0] => 41 [id] => 41
 [1] => Ashok1 [name] => Ashok1 
 [2] => female [gender] => female 
 [3] => 2018-10-25 [dob] => 2018-10-25 
 [4] => ashok1@mail.com [email] => ashok1@mail.com 
 [5] => [password] => 
 [6] => Mech [dept] => Mech
 [7] => Sub1 [subject] => Sub1 
 [8] => address1 [address] => address1 
 [9] => logo_1540534309.png [image] => logo_1540534309.png
 [10] => 1 [status] => 1
 [11] => national,national,international,international,sports,sports 
   [news] => national,national,international,international,sports,sports 
 [12] => english,hindi,english,hindi,english,hindi 
   [LANGUAGE] => english,hindi,english,hindi,english,hindi 
)
```

here array [11] and [12] are getting repeated values which is the table with multiple rows.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT support DISTINCT option  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat .. Besides make sure you set group_concat_max_len before using GROUP_CONCAT on large groups or tables. (also in the manual link i've provided)

Comment: Besides `SELECT form_submitted.*, .... GROUP BY form_submitted.id` isn't techical correct ANSI SQL.. MySQL allowes this because it have a extended GROUP BY "feature" when the server is not running a active sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.. Only problem is that the non aggregated select columns which are not in the GROUP BY can get invalid unrelated data (values) to the GROUP BY group unless MySQL could have used functional dependency to get the correct data which the more modern MySQL versions support.. I believe this is from MySQL version 5.7 and up

Comment: @RaymondNijland that's all well and good, but the MySQL extended GROUP BY is not the issue here

Comment: "but the MySQL extended GROUP BY is not the issue here " MySQL's  extended GROUP BY "feature" is the root of all evil wrong data in MySQL.  @Arth that's why ive mentioned it here... Oh and topicstarter you should also read how to prevent SQL injections in PHP

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well it's not the root of all evil wrong data if it's not the cause of the wrong data here.. that's just bad logic! Personally, I like the feature, it's nice to be able to group by an entire record just by using the PK.

Comment: " I like the feature, it's nice to be able to group by an entire record just by using the PK." Yes i talked about the functional dependency @Arth besides it also works on unique key it does not have to be PK.. "Well it's not the root of all evil wrong data if it's not the cause of the wrong data here.. that's just bad logic!" hard to say without table structure you assume id automatic means PK here thats also bad logic.. We shouldn't even had made comment about this without knowing table structure(s)

Comment: The first line of the question pretty much says there's only one row for the id in that table .. so it's a safe assumption in my eyes. If not, matey can always get back with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

This is because of the way JOIN works

You have 2 corresponding language rows and 3 corresponding news records for the form_submitted id, so these get duplicated

Before the GROUP BY is applied your row set will look like this

```
id .   language .       news . 
41 .   national .       english
41 .   national .       hindi
41 .   international .  english
41 .   international .  hindi
41 .   sports .         english
41 .   sports .         hindi
```

You can see this if you remove the GROUP BY from your query

@RaymondNijland is correct in that GROUP BY (DISTINCT .. ) will fix this for you

Personally I'd want to do these JOINs kinda separately, rather than fix the result afterward.. I'd be tempted to run

```
   SELECT fs.*,
          fsn.news,
          fsl.language

     FROM form_submitted fs

     JOIN (
       SELECT cid,
              GROUP_CONCAT(news) news
         FROM form_submitted_news
        WHERE cid = '$id' /** not strictly necessary, but may improve performance */
     GROUP BY cid
          ) fsn
       ON fsn.cid = fs.id

     JOIN (
       SELECT cid,
              GROUP_CONCAT(language) language
         FROM form_submitted_language
        WHERE cid = '$id' /** not strictly necessary, but may improve performance */
     GROUP BY cid
          ) fsl
       ON fsl.cid = fs.id

    WHERE fs.id = '$id'
```

Comment: Good explaiment why the results are what the topicstarter gets "Personally I'd want to do these JOINs kinda separately, rather than fix the result afterward" Yes rewritting `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...)` suggestion to deliverd tables (subqueries) approach would make more sense performance wise

Comment: Thank you @Arth but my task was to use a single SELECT query to fetch the data .If I use a SELECT inside JOIN again it is like using multiple SELECT.So, I go with    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...)

Comment: @VigneshBalaji Hmm, not really, I believe it’s still a single select query and an atomic statement with nested selects.. but it’s up to you. You can always benchmark the options and see which is faster.